# ReferenceError In my Electron App. Calling a function from other JS file

Tags: javascript, electron, desktop-application

When I want call my function called `Login` or to my `WriteFile` function I have the error:

> ReferenceError: Cannot access 'fs' before initialization

or

> ReferenceError: Cannot acces 'axios before initialization

Anyone knows why?

Rendered.js:

```
btnSingin = document.getElementById('btnsignin');
 
btnSingin.onclick = () => {
    let username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    let paswd = document.getElementById('userpassword').value;
    login(username, paswd);
}
```

Functions.js:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const axios = require('axios');

function login(username, password){
  //A call to a Api with Axios
  axios.post("url").then(resp=>{
     //Make Something
  }
}

function writeFile(){
    fs.appendFileSync('.\\myFile.txt', 'HelloWorld! ', {
           flag: 'a'
    });
}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>MyAPP</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <br>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

            <form action="" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">USERNAME</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                <i class="fa fa-odnoklassniki"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <input id="username" name="user" placeholder="Enter your user name" type="text"
                            class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">PASSWORD</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                <i class="fa fa-key"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <input id="userpassword" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password" type="password"
                            class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button name="submit" id="btnsignin" type="submit" class="btn">LOG IN</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>   
</body>

<script src="./renderer.js"></script>
<script src="./functions.js"></script>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        icon: 'assets/img/iconFarma.png',
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, './renderer.js')
        }
})
mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, './index.html'),
        protocol: 'file',
        slashes: true
 }))
```

Comment: Change the order of calling js file first function then renderer